# Using another class from a thread

Tags: php, pthreads, composer-php

My threaded script doesn't see another class from within a thread. Here is my code.

```
require_once __DIR__.'\vendor\autoload.php';
use Symfony\Component\DomCrawler\Crawler;

$threadCount = 5;
$list = range(0,100);
$list = array_chunk($list, $threadCount);

foreach ($list as $line) {
    $workers = [];
    foreach (range(0,count($line)-1) as $i) {
        $threadName = "Thread #".$i.": ";
        $workers[$i] = new WorkerThreads($threadName,$line[$i]);
        $workers[$i]->start();
    }

    foreach (range(0,count($line)-1) as $i) {
        $workers[$i]->join();
    }
}

class WorkerThreads extends Thread {
    private $threadName;
    private $num;

    public function __construct($threadName,$num) {
        $this->threadName = $threadName;
        $this->num = $num;
    }

    public function run() {
        if ($this->threadName && $this->num) {
            $result = doThis($this->num);
            printf('%sResult for number %s' . "\n", $this->threadName, $this->num);
        }
    }
}

function doThis($num){
    $response = '<html><body><p class="message">Hello World!</p></body></html>';
    $crawler = new Crawler($response);
    $data = $crawler->filter('p')->text();
    return $data;
}
```

When I run it, I get the following error message

`Fatal error: Class 'Symfony\Component\SomeComponent\SomeClass' not found`

How would I make my thread see another class?

Comment: Have you installed that symfony's component?

Comment: @Federkun Yes, I have. If I run `doThis` function outside a thread, everything works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of @Federkun answer, which he deleted, I found the [following thread discussing the issue](https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/5482)

Here is a working solution

```
$autoloader = require __DIR__.'\vendor\autoload.php';
use Symfony\Component\DomCrawler\Crawler;

$threadCount = 1;
$list = range(0,100);
$list = array_chunk($list, $threadCount);


foreach ($list as $line) {
    $workers = [];
    foreach (range(0,count($line)-1) as $i) {
        $threadName = "Thread #".$i.": ";
        $workers[$i] = new WorkerThreads($autoloader,$threadName,$line[$i]);
        $workers[$i]->start();
    }

    foreach (range(0,count($line)-1) as $i) {
        $workers[$i]->join();
    }
}


class WorkerThreads extends Thread {
    private $threadName;
    private $num;

    public function __construct(Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader $loader,$threadName,$num) {
        $this->threadName = $threadName;
        $this->num = $num;
        $this->loader = $loader;
    }

    public function run() {
        $this->loader->register();
        if ($this->threadName && $this->num) {
            $result = doThis($this->num);       
            printf('%sResult for number %s' . "\n", $this->threadName, $this->num);
        }
    }
}



function doThis($num){
    $response = '<html><body><p class="message">Hello World!</p></body></html>';
    $crawler = new Crawler($response);
    $data = $crawler->filter('p')->text();
    return $data;
}
```